# My deleted, not recent questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

How can I access deleted questions not listed at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5306?

E.g., I'm searching one that asked about 'mode' vs 'modality'?

[image]

Comment: I would say that this is off topic for Ling meta, since it's not a question about how Ling SE works, it's a question about how SE works, so it belongs on general Meta SA.

Comment: This is not just searching on Linguistics, it's searching on any Stack Exchange site. So, this belongs on Meta SE.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `modality user:me deleted:yes` — is this what you need?

All search patterns: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Note, your question about modality is here: `modality user:5306 is:question deleted:no`

Comment: I don't think so. Please see the screenshot added to my post.