# Did I ask a question, now deleted, on Loan Translations of 'to wit'?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[Loan Translation is defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword#Linguistic_classification). I see [no deleted recent questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5306).

Comment: [This answer](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1788/1270) tells you how to search for it

Comment: @ba I don't think so. I can't see questions deleted over 30 days ago.

Comment: `user:me deleted:yes` shows me 6 year old questions on another site